# Facebook API post to friends wall

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm building application to post statuses from authenticated users like [that one](http://www.facebook.com/tarekhassan410/posts/366730226754110).

The problem is the application posting from my profile on friends wall who authenticated the application from my profile.

I'm using Facebook API with CodeIgniter.

the code

```
            $userId = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $IDs = $this->facebook_data->get_IDs();
        if(isset($_POST['link'])){
            $args = array(
                'from'  => array('name'=>'Resala','id'=>'294357147348261'),
                'application'=>array('name'=>'XXXX','id'=>'XXXXX'),
                'name'  =>'XXXX',
                'message'   => $_POST['status2'],
                'link'      => $_POST['link']
            );
        }else{
            $args = array(
                'from'  => array('name'=>'Resala','id'=>'294357147348261'),
                'application'=>array('name'=>'Resala','id'=>'XXXXX'),
                'name'  =>'XXXX',
                'message'   => $_POST['status1']
            );
        }
        foreach($IDs->result() as $row){
            $ID=$row->user_id;
            $this->facebook->api("/$ID/feed", "post", $args);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you adding a `from` parameter in your request? where did you see that?

Comment: I'm reading documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ . I added this line trying to make application post just as application and not post on friends wall

Answer (score 1):

The right docs for creating a post are:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

There you can see the params "from" and "application" don't exist and "name (can only be used if link is specified)".

It's not possible to post in the name of an app. You can only post in the name of an page (that may be assosiated with the app). 
Therefor you have to use the page access token instead of the user access token.
See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens